# Why does my ubuntu 20.04 LTS show GRUB command line when I reboot after installing?

Tags: system-installation

So I've been trying to install ubuntu 20.04 LTS all day. And in the final attempt I chose not to restart after installation. Things were working great (it even downloaded the relevant graphics driver) and gave me 4k resolution. But as soon as I shutdown or restart, I end up in the **grub command line**. And if I chose a different drive for booting (i.e. my harddrives that ubuntu is installed on) it stops detecting my monitor. Tried a bunch of things posted on the internet but really would appreciate some help. Again, If I install a new version of the OS and don't restart, it works great. But of course I have to shutdown my pc at some point

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1306628/edit) your question to add info about your hardware.  Also, did you boot the USB stick in UEFI mode?

Comment: I have an i5-4670K CPU, an AMD r9 280x GPU, and 16 GB RAM 
I'm not sure about the USB stick mode (I'll take a look again)
but everything worked great when I install it but as soon as I restart or shutdown, the monitor has no signal anymore

Comment: It means that it is having issues running the installed version (until you restart, it runs from the USB stick and RAM)